# Laravel changing response header if validation fails/succeeds

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, laravel, httpresponse

Laravel has this nice functionality to return JSON if your validation fails.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation

Unfortunately, response headers are set *client-side* like below. It would seem that Laravel would account for successful validation and change the response header to HTML somehow. However, I'm not seeing this documented anywhere. Anyone have a clue?

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "JSON",
    error: function(error){ //422 response, validation errors go here
    success: function(response) { //if validation successful
```

**update**
I"m using the Form Requests rather than controller-based validation, but this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "set client-side" ? Laravel works purely on the server backend. Which headers would you expect and which response headers do you get instead?

Comment: It says that a redirect response is sent back if it is successful. Surely you could just catch this in your AJAX callback and do whatever you want?

Comment: ok that makes sense, can you give a sense of how that looks in the `success(response)` handler?

Comment: And it actually says if its AJAX, **no** redirect will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

With laravel you can change the response header sent to the client through Laravel.

In 5.1 on your controller you can send the response header that you want then have different implementation for them.

```
return response()->json(['message'=>'Error Encountered'],422);
```

this would send back to your client a 422 error. The second arguement you can set differrent http codes depending on what your passing to the client.
Take a look at what the the function accepts at

http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_json

Same is true also for laravel 5.0

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_json

For redirections after validation you can attach a header to it like so

```
return Redirect::back()->header('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
```

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/ResponseTrait.html#method_header

Comment: Thanks @Mwaa. How do I change it to HTML?

Comment: change what in html? The response?

Comment: Yes, the response was set to JSON client-side, but I want to change it in my laravel app to HTML output.

Comment: @timpeterson can you edit the question to include the controller action how your validating. Are you using Form Requests or Normal validation?

Comment: I'm using Form Requests (a custom one). Will edit the question. thanks